# Running Multiplication in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to perform running multiplication using SQL query in MS access database.

```
 SELECT Table.ITEM
,Table.Location
,Table.PATH
,Table.PARENT
,Table.CATEGORY
,Table.origin
,Table.qty
,Table.rate
,(Produced * Rate) AS EFF_Rate
,(
    SELECT max(QTY) AS ProducedQty
    FROM TableAS B
    GROUP BY ITEM
    ) AS Produced
    FROM Table;
```

I am getting this as sample output.(query Result.jpeg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqB1A.jpg)
 want one more column which will provide me running multiplication. For example as per result of your query dataset:

For example if i multiply Max(Qty) i.e. 5026 by Rate it will give me 4931.0086. Now i want to multiply 4931.0086 with 1 (i.e. 2nd row value of rate field) and so on.attached is desired output [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIJKJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I crated a tested table and it works:

```
    SELECT rate,eff_rate,
        (
         case @RunMult when 0 then @RunMult := eff_rate
         else @RunMult := @RunMult * rate end
        ) as RunningMultipl
    FROM rate,
       (SELECT @RunMult:=0) t;
```

Result:

```
    +--------+-----------+----------------+
    | rate   | eff_rate  | RunningMultipl |
    +--------+-----------+----------------+
    | 0.9811 | 4931.0086 |      4931.0086 |
    |      1 |      5026 |      4931.0086 |
    | 0.9278 | 4663.1228 |  4574.98977908 |
    +--------+-----------+----------------+
```

To work as expected in your query it needs some changes:

```
    SELECT t1.*, 
        (
         case @RunMult when 0 then @RunMult := t1.eff_rate
         else @RunMult := @RunMult * t1.rate end
        ) as RunningMultipl
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Table.ITEM
        ,Table.Location
        ,Table.PATH
        ,Table.PARENT
        ,Table.CATEGORY
        ,Table.origin
        ,Table.qty
        ,Table.rate
        ,(Produced * Rate) AS EFF_Rate
        ,(
            SELECT max(QTY) AS ProducedQty
            FROM TableAS B
            GROUP BY ITEM
            ) AS Produced
            FROM Table
        )as t1, 
        (SELECT @RunMult:=0) t2;
```